# Comparing character statistics to produce predetermined third value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a tool which when a Character's name is entered it compares their "weapon skill" against the other entered characters.

I am using a key-pair to represent the character and their stat at the moment and running it through a bunch of conditional checks. I thought I might be able to circumvent all of this by adding a spreadsheet but "Excel 12.0 Object Library" isn't present in my COM list and I can't see any replacements.

Is there a better way of doing this? If statements seem inelegant.

I've searched for objects, DataGridView and Chart sounded hopeful but as far as I can see from the examples I saw and a little fiddle they can't be used how I'd like.

Would appreciate any advice or things to look into!

The data.

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
1   4   4   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
2   3   4   4   4   5   5   6   6   6   6
3   2   3   4   4   4   4   5   5   6   6
4   2   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   5   5
5   2   2   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   4
6   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   4
7   2   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4   4
8   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   4   4   4
9   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   4   4
10  2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   3   4
```

My code.

```
namespace ThereIsOnlyRules
{
public partial class Calculator : Form
{
    public Calculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    StoreVariables test = new StoreVariables();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        test.doWork();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lblwinner.Text = "";
        string attackCharacter = attackBox.Text;
        string opponentCharacter = opponentBox.Text;
        string toHitRoll = test.ToHit(attackCharacter, opponentCharacter);
        lblwinner.Text = toHitRoll;

    }
}
public class StoreVariables
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> attacker = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    public Dictionary<string, int> opponent = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    //string attackUnit { get; set; }
    //string opponentUnit { get; set; }
    int weaponSkill { get; set; }
    public void doWork()
    {
        Attacker();
        Opponent();
        //ToHit();
    }
    private void Attacker()             
    {
        attacker.Add("Warrior", 3);
        attacker.Add("Destroyer", 4);
        attacker.Add("Reaver", 9);
        attacker.Add("Killer", 10);
    }
    private void Opponent()
    {
        opponent.Add("Warrior", 3);
        opponent.Add("Destroyer", 4);
        opponent.Add("Reaver", 9);
        opponent.Add("Killer", 10);
    }
    public string ToHit(string attackerName, string opponentName)
    {
        string toHit = "0";

        int value;
        int AWS = 0;
        int OWS = 0;
        if (attacker.TryGetValue(attackerName, out value))
        {
            AWS = value;
        }
        if (opponent.TryGetValue(opponentName, out value))
        {
            OWS = value;
        }

        if (OWS == 10)
        {
            if (AWS >= 5)
            {
                toHit = "4+";
                return toHit;
            }
            else if (AWS <= 4)
            {
                toHit = "5+";
                return toHit;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else if (OWS == 9)
        {
            if (AWS == 10)
            {
                toHit = "3+";
                return toHit;
            }
            else if (AWS >= 5)
            {
                toHit = "4+";
                return toHit;
            }
            else if (AWS <= 4)
            {
                toHit = "5+";
                return toHit;
            }
            else
            {
                return "I haven't implemented the rest yet, choose Killer as opponent";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel, DataGrid and Chart are having nothing in common with your problem! You have to code it. The problem you have comes out of the fact, that there is no logic for players in your program.

You should use OOP for this. Just a very simple sample to show you the idea (you have to do the OWS-stuff or whatever else inside the Player-class):

```
public abstract class Player : IComparable
{

    public abstract int Skill { get; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Player)
            return this.Skill.CompareTo(((Player) obj).Skill);
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}

public class Warrior : Player
{
    public override int Skill
    {
        get { return 3; }
    }
}

public class Destroyer : Player
{
    public override int Skill
    {
        get { return 4; }
    }
}

public class Game
{

    public Player Attacker { get; set; }

    public Player Opponent { get; set; }

    public bool AttackerWins
    {
        get { return Attacker.CompareTo(Opponent) == 1; }
    }

    public bool OpponentWins
    {
        get { return Opponent.CompareTo(Attacker) == 1; }
    }
}
```

The Game-class just shows the usage. Normally you would implement compare-opertators or do some other comparing.

Comment: [This site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-s-the-difference-between-code-override-code-and-code-new-code.aspx) helped me find out what this code actually did, didn't seem that simple to me. ;D